# ReactJS onClick in list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list and I wanna set onClick event when a list item is clicked. But my function isn't triggered even though I have bind the function.

I have looked at TODO example ([TODO GITHUB](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos/)). In that example, onClick list item will dispatch an action and in the end it will change the Global State (Redux Store).

What I wanna have is, when I click list item, it won't change Global State but it just change local state. I have initialize local state and onClickItemHandler function, but it seems my function isn't executed (no console.log result in chrome console).

Here is my code

```
// Searchable Component
class Searchable extends Component{
  constructor(props,context){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      listAccount: [],
      style:{
        searchResultList:{
          listStyle: 'none',
          width: '100%',
          height: '0em'
        },
        searchResultItem:{
          listStyle: 'none',
          width: '100%',
          height: '0em'
        },
      }
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
    this.onItemClickHandler = this.onItemClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event){
    this.props.onInputChange(this.props.data.type, this.props.data.id,event.target.value);
  }

  onFocus(event){
    console.log("input on focus");
    const showResultList= {
      height: '10em',
      overflow:'auto'
    };

    const showResultItem= {
      height: '2.4em',
      visibility: 'visible'
    };

    let style= this.state.style;
    style.searchResultList = showResultList;
    style.searchResultItem = showResultItem;
    this.setState({style});
  }

  onBlur(event){
    console.log("input on Blur");
    const showResultList= {
      height: '0',
      overflow:'hidden'
    };

    const showResultItem= {
      height: '0',
      visibility: 'collapse'
    };

    let style= this.state.style;
    style.searchResultList = showResultList;
    style.searchResultItem = showResultItem;
    this.setState({style});
  }

  onItemClickHandler(event){
    console.log("test");
    console.log(event.target);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="searchable">
        <input type="search" className="input-searchable" value={this.props.data.input} onChange={this.onChange} onFocus={this.onFocus} onBlur={this.onBlur}/>
        <div className="search-result">
          <SearchResultList
            ResultList={this.props.accounts}
            listStyle={this.state.style.searchResultList}
            listItemStyle={this.state.style.searchResultItem}
            onClick={this.onItemClickHandler}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// SearchResultList Component
const SearchResultList = ({ResultList, listStyle, listItemStyle, onClick}) => (
  <ul style={listStyle} onClick={onClick}>
  {
    ResultList.map((item,idx) =>
      <SearchResultItem
        key={++idx}
        style={listItemStyle}
        text={item.name}
        onClick={onClick}
        />
    )
  }
  </ul>
);


// SearchResultItem Component
const SearchResultItem = ({ onClick, text, style}) => (
  <li
    style={style}
    onClick={onClick}
    >
    {text}
  </li>
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to bind your onClick function:

try

```
    <SearchResultList
      ResultList={this.props.accounts}
      listStyle={this.state.style.searchResultList}
      listItemStyle={this.state.style.searchResultItem}
      onClick={::this.onItemClickHandler}
    />
```

or

```
    <SearchResultList
      ResultList={this.props.accounts}
      listStyle={this.state.style.searchResultList}
      listItemStyle={this.state.style.searchResultItem}
      onClick={this.onItemClickHandler.bind(this)}
    />
```

They do the same thing, binding *this* to your function. I believe it is getting executed upon render because it isn't being bound correctly.

Also, in case you are passing these methods to multiple children and are worried about performance, you can bind in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onItemClickHandler = this.onItemClickHandler.bind(this)
}
```

then use

```
   <SearchResultList
      ResultList={this.props.accounts}
      listStyle={this.state.style.searchResultList}
      listItemStyle={this.state.style.searchResultItem}
      onClick={this.onItemClickHandler}
    />
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do beside binding the function inside render() function?

Comment: Because I think binding function inside render() function will hurt performance (?)

Comment: Yeah, I already bind the function in constructor, but still the function not fired  :'(
*I have edited my code (I put all my code)

Comment: hmm..I'll have to take a look again tomorrow. sorry!

Comment: I've found the answer, and it seems not because the binding method. The main problem is at application flow. I coincidentally remove List Item element before onClick event on that element fired. 
Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about performance you can use es7 class property. You wont need to manually bind your function in the constructor this way. So DRY yay!!

```
    onItemClickHandler = (event) => {
        console.log("test");
        console.log(event.target);
    }
```

Comment: Facebook says that this is 'experimental' syntax, but if it is set up to work then this is a good one too!

Comment: about binding method, I love using React Stateless Functional Component, this article taught me why [link] (https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.wt8tnld3u)

Comment: Yes its experimental. But its here to stay :)